# Did God create evil?

Tags: good-and-evil

I would like to assume some points before asking the main questions.

God did not have a beginning.
God created everything. Not just tangible things but even dreams and imaginations.
There is evil and there is good.
Evil is not a neutral/default state.

So my question is. Did God create evil?
There are some who say that evil is the absence of good.
Then it will mean that evil=neutral. Which means if you are doing nothing(absence of good) therefore you are doing evil things?

The fact that evil still exist comes down to couple possible conclusions.

1. God created evil.
2. God is unable to remove evil from the universe(which is unlikely because he can do anything he wants).

So how do the scriptures explain these?

Comment: This was one of the argument that was recently debated  and was defeated too. [See this link](http://www.apologetics315.com/2013/02/william-lane-craig-vs-alex-rosenberg-debate-mp3-audio.html) and [here](http://www.reasonsforgod.org/2013/02/lessons-from-the-alex-rosenberg-william-lane-craig-debate/) and [video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBTPH51-FoU)